# Remove Views Added in LinearLayout

Tags: android, view, onclick, android-linearlayout

I am adding views in LinearLayout but i am using multiple widgets like

```
CardView cvItem[] = new CardView[fList.size()]; 
TextView tvItem[] = new TextView[fList.size()];

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

 ItemView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                                R.layout.dashboard_item, null);

cvItem[i] = (CardView) ItemView.findViewById(R.id.cvboardItem);
ivItem[i] = (ImageView) ItemView.findViewById(R.id.ivboardItem);
tvItem[i] = (TextView) ItemView.findViewById(R.id.tvboardItem);


if (ItemView.getParent() != null)
((ViewGroup) ItemView.getParent()).removeView(ItemView);
llExpandable.addView(ItemView);
```

> I used that because i want to get onClick for particular position, and by that way i am getting it exactly.

```
cvItem[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                     //My Code...
            }
    });
```

> Please help me, I am using ScrollView so i am not able to use ListView, i tried lots of things on it but nothing worked for me

Comment: Why are you not using a recyclerview or listview for this? They bring the functionality you need with them

Comment: @babadaba i am using all those layout in ScrollView that's why i am not using ListView or any other like that

Comment: Is your ScrollView vertical or horizontal scrolling? Or both? Listviews and Recyclerviews are also scrollable

Comment: @ULHASPATIL, have you tried to delete that view .. if yes please post code

Comment: @MayurRaval Currently i hide that CardView & it is automatically deleted when it reload service.

Comment: @babadaba i am using Vertical ScrollView,  and i don't think ScrollView with ListView is good idea to do.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is not a good idea, but why would you need the Scrollview anyway if you use a ListView or RecyclerView?

Comment: @babadaba Some Views in my Layout is dynamic, it may there or not with images which is not come from backend and some views have expandable depending on there size if not then there views is going to change.

Comment: Then you should use a RecyclerView with different Viewholders and Viewtypes. It's common practise and much more performant and less memory hogging than just adding views to a ScrollView

Comment: @babadaba ok, Thanks, Let me try that :)